# If $X_n$ converges to $X$, does $\sqrt{X_n}$ converge to $\sqrt{X}$ in a general normed space

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

If $X_n$ converges to $X$, does $\sqrt{X_n}$ converge to $\sqrt{X}$ in a general metric space where the metric is created by a norm.  I know that if you use absolute value it does, but does it work for any general norm?  If so, what is the proof?

The space being $\mathbb{R}$ to clarify and the norm being any norm that works on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How is the square root defined in this general metric space?

Comment: What is the normed space in question and what is the square root in that space?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The space being R

Comment: Any norm on $\mathbb R$ is a multiple of the absolute value. If you know that square root is continuous wrt to the absolute value, it is also continuous wrt to any norm...

Answer (score 1):

It is true that for all continuous functions that $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  For the example you gave, realize that $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined for negative $x$ if you want your codomain to be $\mathbb{R}$